# Done button item has a text of Edit

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, uinavigationitem

I have a navbar with a rightbarbuttonitem of:

```
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done)];
```

Though when I compile the app onto a device, the button says edit on it instead of done like it is supposed to. Why is this

I add the button like this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done)];
```

This is the whole code for the view:

```
-(void) done {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.title = @"Edit";
    self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done)];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

I am not using an xib file just pure code and am presenting to the controller from another

Comment: When do you create and add the button? Is the button shown actually that button you created?

Comment: Ok, so what is the top view controller? Is it's view actually on display at the time, or it's mid-push? Does it naturally have its own right bar button item? What happens if you add it on the left instead?

Comment: When are you creating the button? Inside what method of what class?

Comment: You won't want to alloc/init the bar in your code if you already have it in IB. That will create a second version of it and messages can get skewed

Comment: @Wain the topviewcontroller is a way to reference the navigation bar

Comment: @Harsh I have added the full code

Comment: Why are you not using `self.navigationItem` then? What is the top view controller when your code runs? Are you sure??

Comment: This is the only way that works I am sure @Wain

Comment: Then you are doing something wrong. I'm guessing that you are presenting this view controller from another view controller that isn't full screen. Provide details of what is on the screen when this view controller is presented and the code you're using.

Comment: @Wain actually it does work another way which I will post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are using the style of a done button which means it will say edit instead of done as it is basically an edit button which doesn't respond to some selectors edit buttons do. To fix this change your code to this:

```
self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(done)];
```